# Calling a function before the document loads up in JS

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

My friend asks me to do this.

He needs to prevent his children from going to certain websites.

He has tamper monkey installed with chrome. I have to make a script in tamper-monkey so that when it reaches the website it will change the web content.

The source code is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://www.harmful-website.com/*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==
document.write("<b>You are not allowed to visit this site</b>");
```

This script works only after the web-site is loaded full. But his children stop the loading of website in the middle and they are able to view a part of it.

Even `document.onload=function(){document.write("...");}` works after load. Are there any way to make the script run before the document is loaded i.e. Immediately after the web address is typed on the address bar or hyperlink is clicked.

Comment: Why not install a proxy server instead? [PeerGardian](http://sourceforge.net/projects/peerguardian/) would do the job with much less hassle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry , I want to use this chance to enhance my programming skills. Do you help me on using tamper monkey. Also tell me how to remove the hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work, you just need to set [`@run-at document-start`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#@run-at), like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        site blocker
// @match       http://www.harmful-website.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.write ("<b>You are not allowed to visit this site</b>");
```

**Important:**

1. This will work, *for now*, on Chrome and with Tampermonkey, but it does not work on other browsers.  For example, on Firefox, the `document.write` call will throw the error:

   > Error: The operation is insecure.

   (But the page will still be completely blank.)
2. Although a userscript like this will work (mostly); it is a klugey, brittle, low performance approach and is easily defeated.  Here are just a few ways that are better, faster, easier, and harder for savvy kids to kibosh:

   - Use your home router's siteblock and/or parental controls.  Almost every router and/or modem has this feature, these days.
   - Install one of the many extensions that do this kind of blocking.
   - Block the site with an Adblock rule.
   - [Block the site with the machine's hosts file](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/).
   - Use a proxy server.
   - Search on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function right after you define it. Like in the header or somehwere.

However, you need to consider if the function has actually everything it requires, like HTML elements on the page if it access any of them, as those won't necessarily be loaded when calling your function.

Comment: No it doesn't uses any property of the web page

Comment: the calling your function somewhere after the definition should do it

Answer (score 0):

HTML file is parsed row by row. So if your write your < script > just after < html > tag it will be executed before anything else.

Comment: I said "I am writing tamper monkey script".